# Как сделать счетчик кликов по кнопке с куками на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать или может есть готовое решение, счетчик кликов по кнопке на куках.
Механизм следующий на сайте есть поиск и незарегистрированному пользователю, нужно разрешить им пользоваться только 3 раза в день.

```
<form action="">
    <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
    <input id="secret_key" type="hidden" name="secret_key" value="<?php $secret_key; ?>" />
    <button type="button" onclick="send();" id="preloader"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Бестолковое и бесполезное ограничение, очистка куков занимает пару секунд =)

Comment: Ну тогда может к сессии возможно как-то привязать?

Comment: Можно и к сессии, но толк от этого не появится, идентификатор сессии хранится так же в куках....

Comment: А если к сессии и IP? Толк будет?

Comment: Бррр, смотрите сессия = куки, в том плане что значение можно удалить. так что остается только IP, но это как то... может и несколько тысяч человек на 1 IP сидеть =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
function issetCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? true : false
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
}

function setCookie(name, value) {
    var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60000 * 1000);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/" + url_alias + "; expires=" + date.toUTCString()
}
function send() {
var num = getCookie(num) + 1;
if(getCookie(num) >= 3)
var elem = document.getElementById("myForm");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
} else {
setCookie('num', num);
}
```